# How to Fetch Data Once for Both Page Content and Title Using generateMetadata in Next.js(App Router)?

Tags: next.js, app-router

I want to dynamically change the title using Next.js (App Router).
The following code allows me to set it, but it results in fetching data from the same API twice.

Is there a way to reduce this to just one fetch?

```js
export async function generateMetadata() {
  const user = await fetch("/api/user");

  return {
    title: user.name,
  };
}

export default async function UserPage() {
  const user = await fetch("/api/user");

  return <div>{user.name}</div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is not, but that's not a big deal as Next.JS Memoizes the fetched data between `generateMetadata`, `generateStaticParams`, Layouts, Pages, and Server Components.

Source of information:
[Next.JS Documentation - Dynamic Metadata - Good to know](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#dynamic-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

> *I want to dynamically change the title using Next.js (App Router). The following code allows me to set it, but it results in fetching data from the same API twice.*

**Solution :**

> Wrap your API call in react cache `cache`.

**Here's a small example :**

**Folder Structure :**

```
src
└── app
    ├── api
    │   └── users
    │       └── route.js   // /api/users
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── globals.css
    ├── layout.js
    ├── page.js           // homepage localhost:3000
    └── users
        └── page.js       //users page
```

**Users API endpoint** at location `src\app\api\users\route.js` :

```
export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
// ELSE NEXT JS SETS THIS TO 'auto' which often caches the data.
// hence I FORCED IT TO DYNAMIC BCOZ IN REALWORLD THIS DATA WILL KEEP CHANGING

export const revalidate = 0
// ENSURES NO CACHING OF THIS API ROUTE

export async function GET() {

    let CurTime = new Date()
    let TimeCalledAt = `${CurTime.getHours()}:${CurTime.getMinutes()}:${CurTime.getSeconds()}:${CurTime.getMilliseconds()}`

    console.log("Users API Called : ", TimeCalledAt);

    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', {
        method: 'GET'
    })
    const data = await res.json()

    return Response.json({ data })
}
```

**Users Page** at location `src\app\users\page.js` :

```
import { cache } from 'react';

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'
// BCOZ I WANT PG TO BE GENERATED WITH FRESH DATA EVERY TIME WHEN OPENED


// async function GetUsers() {
//     console.log("***** NO Cache ****");

//     let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users', { method: "GET" })
//     let data = await res.json()
//     return data
// }
// // THIS WILL RUN TWICE - to see it RUN TWICE comment the below code, uncomment the above code


const GetUsers = cache(async () => {
    console.log("***** With Cache ****");
    let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/users', { method: "GET" })
    let data = await res.json()
    return data
})
// // THIS WILL RUN ONCE 

export default async function UsersPage() {

    const { data } = await GetUsers()
    // bcoz data is nested inside, {data: []}
    // console.log(data);

    return (
        <ol>
            {
                data.map((v, i) => (
                    <li key={i}>{v.name}</li>
                ))
            }
        </ol>
    );
}

export async function generateMetadata() {
    const { data } = await GetUsers()
    return {
      title: `${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} Found ${data.length} users !`,
    }
}
```

**Explanation :**

- Go to url `http://localhost:3000/users`, title will be `Time Found 10 users !` set in metadata
- In Users page there is cached API & uncached API which is commented out,
- In terminal you will see `Users API Called :  time` which is bcoz of cached API it runs once,
- Now you may uncomment (dont forget to comment cached API) uncached API & see that there will be 2 API
  calls when uncached API runs
- If you see multiple or 4 logs then its bcoz of reactStrictMode, you may disable it. In production it gets disabled by NextJS

**Please Read :**

- **Route Segment Config :**  https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
- **Caching :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#caching
- **cache :** https://react.dev/reference/react/cache
- **Request Memoization :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#request-memoization
- **Caching in Next.js** : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching
- **Duration :** https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#duration

> ***If you have any doubts, then please leave a comment (I will update answer if necessary)***